# Vqmod Nested require_once

Tags: opencart2.x, vqmod

I have a scenario where vqmod is not able to make the modification in opencart.

Scenario.

in the Theme Folder. Header.php, I have a require statement which includes a menu files based on type of menu

I want to make changes in the menu file. Vqmod is not able to reach to that point.

```
header.php
require 'common/header/menu.php';

menu.php
<li>some text</li>
```

In the Menu.php I want to add another LI before using vqmod.

Answer (score 0):

Every nested require should be have a VQMod::modCheck().

In my case in header.php

```
require 'common/header/menu.php';
```

should be replaced with

```
require (VQMod::modCheck('common/header/menu.php'));
```

*** please note that the Paths should be Absolute**